# Use http namespace references in XAML file with XamlParser

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, namespaces

Since I want to make my application as modular for technical support as possible, I'm trying to implement all views, except the main view containing them, of course, in external XAML files and load them at runtime.
I'm using this code:

```
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("SomeXaml.xaml", FileMode.Open);
DependencyObject dependencyObject = XamlReader.Load(fileStream) as DependencyObject;
```

Pretty simple, but works. The problem is, if my XAML has a namespace like that in it:

```
xmlns:dxg="http://schemas.devexpress.com/winfx/2008/xaml/grid"
```

It won't recognize any controls of the dxg namespace. Using

```
xmlns:dxg="clr-namespace:DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.LookUp;assembly=DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v15.1"
```

however, solves the problem. Now it's really a pain in the ass to always define assembly namespaces, especially since some of them are split in various DLLs, while the http namespace would merge some of them, at least.
Is there a way to let my loose XAML recognize these http namespaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have DevExpress, but tried it with a `ResourceDictionary` containing a `Style` for a `XamDataGrid`. That's an Infragistics control in the `xmlns:dataPresenter="http://infragistics.com/DataPresenter"` namespace.

It failed just as you described.
But it succeeded, if I loaded the assembly before doing a `XamlReader.Load`.

```
Assembly.Load("InfragisticsWPF4.DataPresenter.v15.2");
var fileStream = new FileStream("SomeResourceDictionary.xaml", FileMode.Open);
ResourceDictionary dict = XamlReader.Load(fileStream) as ResourceDictionary;
```

So I assume what you'd need in your case, according to [this](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/CustomDocument7385) is the following:

```
Assembly.Load("DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v15.2");
Assembly.Load("DevExpress.Xpf.Grid.v15.2.Core");
FileStream fileStream = new FileStream("SomeXaml.xaml", FileMode.Open);
DependencyObject dependencyObject = XamlReader.Load(fileStream) as DependencyObject;
```

These XML namespace to CLR namespace mappings are defined in the `AssemblyInfo.cs` file using the [`XmlnsDefinitionAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.markup.xmlnsdefinitionattribute(v=vs.110).aspx), it seems that the `XamlReader` doesn't know about them until you loaded the assembly and its manifest was properly read.

Comment: That's exactly what I needed, been searching for hours! Thanks!
I was wondering since it worked when I used something from the DLL before loading the XAML, guess the XamlParser is satisfied with loading the assembly beforehand.

Answer (score -1):

add Devexpress dll file's Reference into Project

Comment: That's only gonna help if he uses anything from the dll before trying to load it with `XamlReader`. For example if he does `var gridControl = new GridControl();` before `XamlReader.Load`, it's gonna work. The actual loading of the assemblies only happen when you are using something from the assembly.